# How to set landscape mode when using pdfbox's texttopdf in command line?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox's texttopdf feature to convert a text file to pdf. I am using the **command line** version of pdfbox.

How to mention that the output should be a landscape A4?

This is the command that I am using right now :

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.8.jar TextToPDF -fontSize 8 out.pdf in.txt
```

I would really appreciate if I can mention the landscape flag in the command line itself.
Much thanks!

Comment: What happened when you used the "-landscape" flag? Because that one is available in 2.0.8. Upcoming 2.0.9 ( https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.9-SNAPSHOT/ ) will have a few more options (sizes).